# Get length of string method Java

Tags: java, string, string-length

I need to do this:
Create a program that asks for the user's name and says how many characters the name contains.
Your program should be structured so that you put the calculating of the name length in it's own method: public static int calculateCharacters(String text). The tests will be testing both the method calculateCharacters and the program overall.

I know how to count the characters in a string. I just can't figure out how to do this when I have to use a seperate method. Can someone please help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LengthOfName {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type your name: ");
    String name = reader.nextLine ();
    int cal = calculateCharacters(name);
    System.out.println(Number of characters: " + cal);

}


public static int calculateCharacters(String text) {
    int cal = text.length ();
    //System.out.println("Number of characters: " + count ());
    return cal;`
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing?

Comment: I can't see the problem.

Comment: @Kim, I only see one problem with this and its that you didn't put starting quotes on `System.out.println("Number of characters: " + cal`);

Comment: Oh wow. Yes, that was it. Haha, so stupid. I was working on it for a long time. I didn't see it anymore. And didn't know what else to try. Thxxxxx :)

Comment: I can't believe that String.length is meant. Maybe the nonblank characters or the distinct nonblank characters are to count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the error? I'm not seeing any errors in logic here, just a couple syntax issues like missing a quotation mark around "Number of characters: ", a missing curly brace at the end of the calculateCharacters method, and an extra whitespace between reader.nextLine and ().

Your method call itself looks fine.

Comment: Yesss. It works now. Thanks all :). I was getting blind. Was working on it for a long time. Didn't know what else to try. Haha, so stupid |s.